# Find all URLs for a post

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I would like to extract all the links to posts from a wordpress
blog. This seems straight-forward and easy enough to do using
wp-cli. For example:

```
wp post list --field=url --post_type=post --posts_per_page=-1 --post_status=publish
```

However, my site is more complicated, because I have changed permalink
structure on my site at one point in time. Now, wordpress appears to
have done the sensible thing here; all the permalinks that existed
before were kept and are being redirected, using 301 redirects. This
is great, for the life of me I cannot find where it is possible to see
these redirects. I have tried searching the wordpress editing
interface and can't find anything there, and the code reference.

Is there a way to fetch all the URLs that wordpress redirects to
somewhere else? Or all the URLs that redirect to a given post?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that WP does NOT create these 301s automatically on URL change, because I have seen certain plugins such as https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ that have this feature (see below).. also not sure what you want to extract? just a list of all of your current post URLs? or the onpage links out?

"The plugin can also be configured to monitor when post or page permalinks are changed and automatically create a redirect to the new URL."

Comment: I want to extra a list of all URLs whether these URLs are canonical or not. If they resolve to a page, I want to catch them. I am not using a redirection plugin, but wordpress is definately returning 301 redirects for old permalinks.

Comment: I'm like 95% sure WP out of the box would NOT create these redirects for you and I tested it just now also, got a 404. see option 4 https://yoast.com/create-301-redirect-wordpress/ this is up to date, why would it be offered as a feature if out of the box it happened. So the first thing you need to do is find out what is creating these 301s for you. is it a plugin, your theme, your server, CDN?

Comment: Yes, I am confused by this, although the yoast site does not reference to changing permalink structure. Note that I only get 301s for posts already published. New posts just get the new permalink structure. I changed the permalink structure over a decade ago, so who knows maybe something that has changed in that time.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, worked it out. Wordpress *does* create redirects, but they are not in the database. It just guesses. Will answer my own question!

Comment: glad you found the solution. Ya WP does attempt permalink guesses. They are technically not "redirects" as we use the term even though they do redirect you. They are not physically set where they will effect your SEO etc and just happen live when resolving the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what is happening. Wordpress does not store permalinks that were previously made. What it does do is guess what link you want by looking at the post name.

Consider:

```
https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/

wget https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/
--2021-12-31 00:09:51--  https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/
Resolving wordpress.com (wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.17, 192.0.78.9
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.17|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

All makes sense, but now also:

```
wget https://wordpress.com/blog/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/
--2021-12-31 00:10:19--  https://wordpress.com/blog/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/
Resolving wordpress.com (wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.17, 192.0.78.9
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.17|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/ [following]
```

Or:

```
wget https://wordpress.com/blog/new-year-new-success/
--2021-12-31 00:10:54--  https://wordpress.com/blog/new-year-new-success/
Resolving wordpress.com (wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.17, 192.0.78.9
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.17|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/ [following]
--2021-12-31 00:10:55--  https://wordpress.com/blog/2021/12/16/new-year-new-success-with-bloganuary/
Reusing existing connection to wordpress.com:443.
```

It even works with just one letter although this resolves to different (older) post

```
wget https://wordpress.com/blog/n
--2021-12-31 00:11:41--  https://wordpress.com/blog/n
Resolving wordpress.com (wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.9, 192.0.78.17
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.9|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.com/blog/2013/12/03/nablopomo-2013/ [following]
--2021-12-31 00:11:41--  https://wordpress.com/blog/2013/12/03/nablopomo-2013/
Reusing existing connection to wordpress.com:443.
```

So this is why I cannot find them in the database. They don't exist there. The solution is to simply pull the old URLs out of archive.org which has preserved them for me.